# Brakes grinding when roads are snowy

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, abs

I have a 2013 Chevy Cruise that has new brakes changed by the dealership, and they work perfectly in the rain, and dry conditions. But when there's snow on the ground, the brakes often start grinding, and I can feel it in the pedal (I can also hear it). This happens at the end of the stop. I assume it has something to do with the ABS mechanism in the car.

Why only when it's snowy?

What is happening when this occurs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Normal Sounds**

The sound you are hearing is the ABS releasing pressure within the system to allow the wheels to continue to rotate and not lock up when you apply the brakes in low friction conditions.

As the snow builds up and you encounter low friction driving conditions due to snow and ice the ABS will kick in more frequently because you are encountering low friction conditions.

The 'grinding' you hear and feel in your peddle is by design.  You have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if this feature is in all cars that have ABS?

Comment: What you are describing I would consider normal behavior for most ABS vehicles.  There may be newer models that act/react to braking under low friction conditions differently.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if ABS is kicking in, the driver is probably driving too aggressively. To test if it's the ABS, driving in regular conditions on a _clear and empty_ road and panic stopping should show identical response in the brake pedal to what the OP is experiencing when it's snowing.